# No entity column was found using typeorm find nest js

Tags: nestjs, node.js-typeorm

I am trying to add a filter in the relations in the next js

```
    const user = await this.usersRepository.findOne(id, {
        relations:['albums'],
        where: {
            albums: {
               isActive: true,
            }
        }
    });
```

Suppose I have below type of records set and want to filter the item with this record who has isActive: true only
{
id: 1,
name: "Me and Bears",
description: "I am near polar bears",
filename: "photo-with-bears.jpg",
albums: [{
id: 1,
name: "Bears",
isActive: true
}, {
id: 2,
name: "Me",
isActive: false
}]
}

required output
{
id: 1,
name: "Me and Bears",
description: "I am near polar bears",
filename: "photo-with-bears.jpg",
albums: [{
id: 1,
name: "Bears",
isActive: true
}]
}

Can somebody help me what is wrong or how to implement it

Comment: This error was happening for me when in my entity I didn't use the @Column() decorator for some properties.